# What is this veggie sold as "leek sprout" in an Asian market?

Tags: vegetables, food-identification

What is this veggie I bought at the Asian market? It was called a leek sprout.

[image]

Comment: Leek sprout to me sounds like it's a baby leek.

Answer (score 24):

[Yellow Chinese chives](https://thewoksoflife.com/chinese-ingredients-glossary/chinese-chives-scallions-aromatics-peppers/).  These are the same as Chinese garlic chives, but they've been "bleached" by covering them; this results in a milder, sweeter flavor.

They're generally minced and put into dishes as a finishing step.

Comment: Given it came rom asian market, I assume you are right. But it looks very much like Bulgarian garlic chives. We call it `green garlic`. I didn't know about bleaching.

Comment: @akostadinov "Bleaching" isn't quite the right word - plants left in the dark will not develop as much chlorophyll, so it's more that they don't turn green to begin with and not that the green has been "bleached" out after having previously been green.  I don't think you find these sun-deprived yellow chives in traditional European or Balkan cuisine - usually just normal green ones.

Comment: I think "blanching" is the typical term, even though it's easy to confuse with the act of cooking. See [Cauliflower Blanching](https://gardenerspath.com/plants/vegetables/blanch-cauliflower-heads/).

Comment: The botanical name is 'Etiolation' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiolation - it's the same process done with white asparagus and forced rhubarb. Apparently if you go into a dark 'forcing' shed you can actually hear the asparagus growing!